# $\left< 15\right>^7/15$-womcode construction

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, projective-geometry, coding-theory, finite-geometry

In the article [Womcodes constructed with projective geometries](http://documents.irevues.inist.fr/handle/2042/1590) Frans Merkx constructed several good wom-codes (write-once memory codes, see [How to reuse a "write-once" memory](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82585075.pdf) by *Rivest  & Shamir* for classical introduction). But the code $\left< 15\right>^7/15$ (which allows to write 7 times a number from 1 to 15  in 15 write-once bit positions (wits)) was described without any technical details. The author refers to his report *F. Merkx, Codes for Write-Once Memories, Rapport Interne, Ecole Nationale Superieure des Telecommunications, Paris, 1984* which is not available online.

Are there any books or articles containing detailed description of the code $\left< 15\right>^7/15$?

This is the [link](https://catalogue-bibliotheques.imt.fr/cgi-bin/koha/opac-detail.pl?biblionumber=40917) to French library containing Merxk's report but unfortunately it is out of reach for me.

Comment: I saw a lecture which described how to use a Fano plane for this problem with smaller parameters. It feels like a projective plane would be used for this problem.  Gerhard "Is Struggling To Remember Parameters" Paseman, 2019.08.23.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman This case corresponds to projective space $PG(3,2)$. Fano plane gives $⟨7⟩^3/7$-wom-code, it is clear. The code $⟨15⟩^7/15$ can be implemented in different ways. It would be interesting to compare our algorithms with original Merkx's approach.

Comment: the library link you added says "Communicable sur demand" --- suggesting you can just ask for a copy...

Comment: @CarloBeenakker It is not clear how can I do it. Probably I'll write on their email.